# Spring MVC controller with multi URI

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to handle my requests.
 Here I hope the page redirecting to 'admin/login.jsp' when I visit 'http://localhost:8080/test/admin/login', but things that it turns to '/test/admin/WEB-INF/view/jsp/admin/login.jsp' without handling '/login'.

Here are some codes :)

```
 // controller
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/admin")
 public class PageTest {
   @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView test() {
     ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("admin/login");
     return view;
   }
 }

 // spring-context.xml
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/view/jsp/" />
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

 // web.xml
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-context.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 // directory structure like this
 src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/jsp
  - admin
    - login.jsp
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: is the page you want to return namely login.jsp

Comment: please add the directory structure to the question.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you think `InternalResourceViewResolver` and `ModelAndView` do?

Comment: Hey bro, firstly thanks a lot ! Here is the directory structure :
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/jsp/admin/login.jsp  I've added it at the end of my question : )

Comment: I still have no idea what you think the problem is.

Comment: single url request is ok , eg. url '/admin' could load 'admin/login.jsp', and I what I hope is to change the single to multi request '/admin/login', also load to 'admin/login.jsp', that's all bro : )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems everything is alright. Your method will handle "/admin/login" URL and everything it does is returning "admin/login.jsp".

Comment: Try to use String return value and return "admin/login". Look more here:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/87590-resolve-view-names-to-different-folders

Comment: How is that different from the view name in the `ModelAndView` they are already returning?